# SQL Server 2008 how can I do a subquery of this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
select 
    coalesce(NULLIF(No_Parte,' '), NULLIF(OEM,' '), Num_serie) as Producto, 
    Id_Sucursal, Tipo_Movimiento, Cantidad, Costo,No_Servicio, 
    F_Entrada, F_Salida, Observaciones,
    (case 
        when F_Entrada > F_Salida 
           then F_Entrada 
           else F_Salida 
     end) as Fecha
from 
    Kardex_Producto
where
    Id_Sucursal = 'tehuacan' 
    and ((F_Entrada >= CONVERT(DateTime, '20161031', 103) OR F_Salida  >= CONVERT(DateTime, '20161031', 103))
    and (F_Entrada <= CONVERT(DateTime, '20161031', 103) OR F_Salida  <= CONVERT(DateTime, '20161031', 103))) --and Tipo_Movimiento='S-'
order by 
    Tipo_Movimiento, No_Servicio
```

But for some reason it doesn't work as expected, for some reason, it is returning

```
    +------------+-------------+-----------------+----------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
|  Producto  | Id_Sucursal | Tipo_Movimiento | Cantidad |  Costo  |   No_Servicio    |        F_Entrada        |        F_Salida         |                   Observaciones                   |          Fecha          |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+----------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1TU3CWH    | TEHUACAN    | E+              | 1.00     |      0  | Traspaso No. 568 | 2016-11-11 19:19:43.447 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 |                                                   | 2016-11-11 19:19:43.447 |
| 23651      | TEHUACAN    | E+              | 1.00     |      0  | Traspaso No. 569 | 2016-11-14 12:29:21.663 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 |                                                   | 2016-11-14 12:29:21.663 |
| 37035      | TEHUACAN    | E+              | 2.00     |      0  | Traspaso No. 569 | 2016-11-14 12:29:20.657 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 |                                                   | 2016-11-14 12:29:20.657 |
| 39657      | TEHUACAN    | E+              | 2.00     |      0  | Traspaso No. 569 | 2016-11-14 12:29:19.403 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 |                                                   | 2016-11-14 12:29:19.403 |
| 37069      | TEHUACAN    | E+              | 6.00     |      0  | Traspaso No. 571 | 2016-11-17 15:29:30.147 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 |                                                   | 2016-11-17 15:29:30.147 |
| 37282      | TEHUACAN    | E+              | 1.00     |      0  | Traspaso No. 571 | 2016-11-17 15:29:29.503 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 |                                                   | 2016-11-17 15:29:29.503 |
| 37069      | TEHUACAN    | S-              | 1.00     |      0  | 0000000002368    | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-10-31 18:07:05.880 | Venta de Mostrador con numero de ticket indicado. | 2016-10-31 18:07:05.880 |
| 44259      | TEHUACAN    | S-              | 1.00     |      0  | 0000000002369    | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-11-03 15:59:39.307 | Venta de Mostrador con numero de ticket indicado. | 2016-11-03 15:59:39.307 |
| 37069      | TEHUACAN    | S-              | 1.00     |      0  | 0000000002370    | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-11-04 11:07:04.713 | Venta de Mostrador con numero de ticket indicado. | 2016-11-04 11:07:04.713 |
| 39510      | TEHUACAN    | S-              | 1.00     |      0  | 0000000002370    | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-11-04 11:07:05.553 | Venta de Mostrador con numero de ticket indicado. | 2016-11-04 11:07:05.553 |
| 302H493011 | TEHUACAN    | S-              | 1.00     |      0  | 0000000002371    | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-11-04 20:07:17.730 | Venta de Mostrador con numero de ticket indicado. | 2016-11-04 20:07:17.730 |
+------------+-------------+-----------------+----------+---------+------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

but it really should be returning 1 row

```
| 37069      | TEHUACAN    | S-              | 1.00     | 180.00  | 0000000002368    | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2016-10-31 18:07:05.880 | Venta de Mostrador con numero de ticket indicado. | 2016-10-31 18:07:05.880 |
```

My guess it is because both columns (F_entrada and F_Salida), so I decided to "join" them on the column Fecha (the last one), and now I want to filter the data by the column "Fecha", but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `select * from (myquery) t` is the basic way to put something in a subquery (though youd need to take out the `order by` part). Out of interest, is there any particular reason your where clauses look like that? You shouldn't need to convert '20161031' to a datetime...

Comment: To me your query returns the expected result. What is your search criteria actually? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer!
When I started to improve this system, my queries didn't work if I used ('yyyyMMdd'), that's why I had to convert. I'll delete it and check if it works now.
Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @ydoow, the thing is I don't know what I am doing wrong, but it is returning more rows than the expected. The querie should return only 1 row, but it is returning more. It is probably I don't have the where part correctly done, but I already try to change it and nothing worked :-(

Comment: @antonio_veneroso you need to explain the searching criteria to be used in WHERE clause, rather than the expected record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options here:

1. Add the `(CASE WHEN... )` statement to the `where` clause like this

   `WHERE Id_Sucursal='tehuacan' 
   AND (case when F_Entrada>F_Salida then F_Entrada else F_Salida end) <= CONVERT(DateTime, '20161031', 103)`
2. Wrap your existing select statement as a sub-query that calculates the fecha then you can use fecha in the outer query. like this

`SELECT * FROM
(
      select coalesce(NULLIF(No_Parte,' '), NULLIF(OEM,' '),Num_serie) as
             Producto, Id_Sucursal, Tipo_Movimiento, Cantidad,
             Costo,No_Servicio, F_Entrada, F_Salida, Observaciones, 
             (case when F_Entrada>F_Salida then F_Entrada else F_Salida end) as Fecha
     from Kardex_Producto
) as product
WHERE Id_Sucursal='tehuacan' 
    AND Fecha <= CONVERT(DateTime, '20161031', 103) 
order by Tipo_Movimiento, No_Servicio`

Comment: Didn't understand de first option, but the second one worked, thank you!